# How to import data immediately when a page is being built using with the Flutter table calendar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Currently, I'm making a ToDo app using table calendar with Flutter.

The action is to import the ToDo List for that day when you click the date of the table calendar.

It retrieves the todo list for the date selected on the calendar table.

However, the problem is that when you first enter the totoList page, you must click on the date, in order to receive the totoList for that date.

So I want to know how to get the TODO LIST of the day immediately when I access the todoList page instead of having to select the specific date

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:take_a_note_project/model/todo_model.dart';
import 'package:take_a_note_project/todoList/header.dart';
import 'package:take_a_note_project/todoList/todoList_handler.dart';

class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _TodoListState createState() => _TodoListState();
}

class _TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
    Header header;
    TodoModel todoModel;
    CalendarController controller;
    TodoListHandler todoListHandler;
    static TextEditingController eventController;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        header = Header();
        controller = CalendarController();
        eventController = TextEditingController();
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        todoListHandler = Provider.of<TodoListHandler>(context);
        return Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xffFEE8D6),
                body: SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
        _TableCalendar(),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                children: [
        _OnProgressBox(),
                _DoneBox()
                                        ]
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                          )
                      ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.create),
                onPressed: _showAddDialog,
                      ),
                    );
    }

    Widget _OnProgressBox() {
        return Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
        Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
        color: Color(0xffFFF8DC),
                child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 50,),
        ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: todoListHandler.onProgressTodo.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
                    child: todoCard(
                    context, todoListHandler.onProgressTodo, index),
                    onTap: () {
                todoListHandler.onProgressTodo[index].isDone = 1;
                todoListHandler.setTodo(
                        todoListHandler.onProgressTodo[index]);
                todoListHandler.relodeTodos(controller.selectedDay);
            },
                                      );
        }
                                ),
        SizedBox(height: 20,)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
        Header.getCardHeader(
                context: context, text: "TO DO", customColor: Color(0xffca3e47)),
                        ]
                    );
    }

    Widget _DoneBox() {
        return Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
        Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
        color: Colors.grey,
                child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 50,),
        ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: todoListHandler.doneTodo.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
                    child: todoCard(
                    context, todoListHandler.doneTodo, index),
                    onTap: () {
                todoListHandler.doneTodo[index].isDone = 0;
                todoListHandler.setTodo(todoListHandler.doneTodo[index]);
                todoListHandler.relodeTodos(controller.selectedDay);
            },
                                      );
        }
                                ),
        SizedBox(height: 20,)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
        Header.getCardHeader(
                context: context, text: "DONE", customColor: Color(0xff34465d)),
                        ]
                    );
    }

    Widget _TableCalendar() {
        return TableCalendar( // Calendar Style
                initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
                events: todoListHandler.events,
                calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                // Calendar Style
                todayColor: Colors.orange,
                selectedColor: Theme
                .of(context)
                .primaryColor,
                todayStyle: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
        headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                centerHeaderTitle: true,
                formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
                        ),
        formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
        calendarController: controller,
                onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) {
            setState(() {
                print(events);
                todoListHandler.selectedEvents = events;
                todoListHandler.relodeTodos(controller.selectedDay);
            });
        },
        builders: CalendarBuilders(
                selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) =>
        Container(
                child: Text(
                date.day.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme
                .of(context)
                .primaryColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                            ),
        todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) =>
        Container(
                child: Text(
                date.day.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                              ),
                            ),
                      ),
                    );
    }

    _showAddDialog() {
        showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) =>
        AlertDialog(
                title: Text(
                "할 일을 추가합니다.", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        elevation: 24.0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
                              ),
        content: TextField(
                controller: eventController,
                              ),
        actions: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
        RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue)
                                        ),
        child: Text("Save", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.lightBlue),),
        onPressed: () {
            todoListHandler.addTodoList(
                    controller.selectedDay, eventController);
            Navigator.pop(context);
        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                    );
    }

    changeList(todoItem) {
        showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) =>
        AlertDialog(
                title: Text(
                "할 일을 수정합니다.", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
                              ),
        content: TextField(controller: eventController),
        actions: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
        RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue)
                                          ),
        child: Text("Save", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.lightBlue),),
        onPressed: () {
            todoItem.todo = eventController.text;
            todoListHandler.setTodo(todoItem);
            todoListHandler.relodeTodos(controller.selectedDay);
            eventController.clear();
            Navigator.pop(context);
        }
                                      ),
        SizedBox(width: 10.0),
        RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent)
                                        ),
        child: Text("Cancel", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),),
        onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                    );
    }

    deleteList(todoItem) {
        showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) =>
        AlertDialog(
                title: Center(
                child: Text(
                "정말 삭제하시겠어요?", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                              ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
                              ),
        actions: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
        RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue)
                                          ),
        child: Text("Yes", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.lightBlue),),
        onPressed: () {
            todoListHandler.deleteTodo(todoItem.key);
            todoListHandler.relodeTodos(controller.selectedDay);
            Navigator.pop(context);
        }
                                      ),
        SizedBox(width: 10.0),
        RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent)
                                        ),
        child: Text("Cancel", style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),),
        onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                    );
    }

    Widget todoCard(BuildContext context, todoItem, int index) {
        Icon leading;
        Color color;
        Color titleColor;
        int isDone = todoItem[index].isDone;
        String toDo = todoItem[index].todo;

        if (isDone == 1) {
            color = Colors.white38;
            leading = Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.white);
            titleColor = Colors.white;
        } else {
            color = Color(0xffEEE8CD);
            leading = Icon(Icons.radio_button_unchecked, color: Colors.black38,);
            titleColor = Colors.black;
        }

        return Card(
                elevation: 5,
                color: color,
                child: ListTile(
                leading: leading,
                title: Text(toDo, style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20, color: titleColor)),
        trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                onPressed: () {
            settingBox(context, todoItem[index]);
        },
                          ),
                        )
                    );
    }

    Widget updateTodo(BuildContext context, todoItem) {
        return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
                title: Text("To Do 수정"),
                onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            changeList(todoItem);
        },
                    );
    }

    Widget deleteTodo(BuildContext context, todoItem) {
        return ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                title: Text("To Do 삭제"),
                onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            deleteList(todoItem);
        },
                    );
    }

    settingBox(BuildContext context, todoItem) {
        showBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
        return Container(
                color: Color(0xFF737373),
                height: 115,
                child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme
                .of(context)
                .canvasColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(10),
                                    )),
        child: Column(
                children: [
        updateTodo(context, todoItem),
                deleteTodo(context, todoItem)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                          );
                        }
                    );
    }
```

Comment: Just show calendar for current date on first enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
onCalendarCreated: (DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
  selectDay(DateTime.now());
},
```